# Android - How to show a clock in a TimePickerDialog on API19

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-timepicker

How is it possible to show a clock when opening a TimePickerDialog on preAPI21? I'm using appcompat-22 and I even found a way to show the new switch widget. I know how to change it in a regular layout: timePickerMode="clock/spinner" but couldn't find how to do it when opening a TimePickerDialog on API 19.

Please advice

Comment: This question has an answer in a more recent question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706243/timepicker-clock-mode-below-lollipop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TimePicker Clock mode below Lollipop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706243/timepicker-clock-mode-below-lollipop)