# TimePicker Clock mode below Lollipop

Tags: android, timepicker

I am trying to make my `TimePicker` appear as a clock. I use `timepickermode="clock"` but I get a lint warning that says that it's compatible with api level 21 and above.

I've seen this feature ran on my kitkat in Todoist app. How else do I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `TimePicker` with clock look in version prior Lollipop as stated by the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#timePickerMode):

> **timePickerMode**
>   Defines the look of the widget. Prior to the L release, the only choice was spinner. As of L, with the Material theme
>   selected, the default layout is clock, but this attribute can be used
>   to force spinner to be used instead.

There is an alternative offered by Google itself. It is an external datepicker project that is compatible with API level 14 and higher. You can find the project here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/

Once you clone the repo, add it to your existing project, then you can use the `TimePicker` like this:

```
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog();
timePickerDialog.setOnTimeSetListener(new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    }
});
timePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), fragmentTag);
```

Be careful to import the `com.android.datetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog` not the standard `android.app.TimePickerDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/rey5137/material) is good library which brings some Material widget to Pre-lolipop devices , You can find time-picker too.